# React.useState with animation and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement animation using a wrapper component using useState and useEffect.

If a certain value on the props change I would like that to trigger the start of the animation:

```
const propVal = getter(props);
const mounted = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
  //code to initialize and start animation removed

  //because a started animation uses requestAnimationFrame
  //a component may want to set state for animation while not
  //mounted anymore, prevent the error by setting mounted to false
  return () => (mounted.current = false);
}, [propVal]);//<--if propVal changes the animation starts
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/data-list/blob/master/Animate/index.js)

The propVal could be the id of an item (new item will animate in) or a property called `deleted` indicating an item has been removed (should animate out)

I am trying to create a smaller code example to re produce the problem I am facing but was not able (yet) to do so.

The problem is that if I delete an item of then the `mounted.current = false` (returned callback from useEffects) part gets called even though the component did not unmount.

When I change the code to `return () => false && (mounted.current = false);` basically removing the safeguard to prevent unmounted components from animating then deleting an item will animate without error. This tells me that the component is not unmounted but somehow the returned callback for onUnmount is called.

Sorry for not (yet) being able to provide a simpler reproduction of this problem. Maybe someone knows why the callback would be called when the component is obviously not unmounted (removing the safe guard does not cause errors and animates as expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you should set the mounted ref to true in the effect.
Otherwise, any change to the propVal dependency will stop recurAnimate from working.

Say the value changes from an id => to "deleted", 
The cleanup effect runs but the component isn't unmounted,
then the effect runs again with the new value, but the isMounted ref 
keeps recurAnimate locked.

edit: The cleanup function returned from the effect !== componentWillUnmount.
It will run every time the effect will be rerun, and then lastly when the component unmounts.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I see that the returned "cleanup" function is called [multiple times](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) and not just on unmount. It says: `Additionally, if a component renders multiple times (as they typically do), the previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect.` . Your answer helped me solve the problem without using useRef and do it [this way](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/data-list/commit/c83f05516d136a65b4edc8d077324711da17b342)